# getting error in Sql Query incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling

I getting the error when I execute this query

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15  Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I am unable to find the cause of error .please help what is wrong in my query

```
 Select 
        SIHDR.[Posting Date],   
        SIHDR.[Bill-to Contact No_],    
        SIHDR.[Order No_],  
        SILIN.[Bom Item No_],   
        ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar (30),(Select Description from [Item] where No_ = SILIN.[Bom Item No_])),''), 
        SILIN.[No_],    
        SILIN.[Line No_],   
        CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description]),  
        CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description 2]),    
        CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description 3]),    
        SILIN.[Subscription Starting Date], 
        SILIN.[Subscription End Date],   

        SUM(CASE WHEN SIHDR.[Currency Factor]=0 THEN SILIN.[Selling Price] ELSE SILIN.[Selling Price]) as Selling_Price_INR


        FROM  [Sales Shipment Header] as SIHDR  
        INNER JOIN [Sales Shipment Line] as SILIN  on SIHDR.No_ = SILIN.[Document No_]  

        enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE` needs an `END`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN SIHDR.[Currency Factor]=0 THEN SILIN.[Selling Price] ELSE SILIN.[Selling Price] END) as Selling_Price_INR
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `end` is missing in your second `case` statement.

```
    Select 
    SIHDR.[Posting Date],   
    SIHDR.[Bill-to Contact No_],    
    SIHDR.[Order No_],  
    SILIN.[Bom Item No_],   
    ISNULL(
        CONVERT(varchar (30),
            (Select Description from [Info Edge (India) Ltd$Item] where No_ = SILIN.[Bom Item No_])
            ),''),   
    SILIN.[No_],    
    SILIN.[Line No_],   
    CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description]),  
    CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description 2]),    
    CONVERT(varchar (30),SILIN.[Description 3]),    
    SILIN.[Subscription Starting Date], 
    SILIN.[Subscription End Date],   

    SUM(
        CASE WHEN SIHDR.[Currency Factor]=0 
        THEN SILIN.[Selling Price] 
        ELSE SILIN.[Selling Price] 
        END      ---- this end is missing in your query.
        ) as Selling_Price_INR


    FROM  [Sales Shipment Header] as SIHDR  
    INNER JOIN [Sales Shipment Line] as SILIN  on SIHDR.No_ = SILIN.[Document No_]
```